# Manage a large project in Overleaf

Tags: table-of-contents, input, overleaf, large-files

I'm trying to manage a large project which is my Graduation Report , I'm trying to import each chapter , in the 1st chapter everything was fine and each section appeared correctly in the table of contents but it didn't work with chapter 2 
**This is the main :**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\definecolor{darkcandyapplered}{rgb}{0.64, 0.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{odoopurple}{rgb}{0.57, 0.36, 0.51}
\title{Rapport de stage de fin d'\'etude}
\author{Hello world}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des mati\'eres}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\chapter{Étude préliminaire}
\input{Chapitre 1}
\chapter{Le Backlog du produit}
\input{Chapitre 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try deleting your `.aux` files (which Overleaf calls "Cached Files" in the Recompile contextual menu)  and recompiling. Assuming chapter 2 has no errors, you're not doing anything wrong. (Although you should let `babel` rename your table of contents automatically, as it will get the spelling right...)

Comment: Maybe use `include`. It uses the same syntax as `input`.

Comment: @Someone `\include` will add a `\clearpage` so the `\chapter` commands would be better off inside the included file. There's nothing wrong with using `\input` here.

Comment: @AlanMunn i checked the logs and output files to delete cached files i found so many errors like this one `LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` even though i imported all the packages before \begin document in the main and in the chapitre 1 and chapitre 2  files .

Comment: Then your problem has nothing to do with `\input` but with the code in chapter 2. Is the error the first error? What does the rest of the error say (you can edit your question). If you're having difficulty finding the code that's causing the error, put an `\end{document}` line into chapter 2 and move it successively until it compiles.

Comment: Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. I don't know from your post what could cause this. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: Put the packages into a dedicated package file using the `sty` extension. This will prevent unintentional double imports.

Comment: It also prevents large, messy preambles.

Comment: How about `\import`? It uses the `import` package. It uses the syntax `\import{FilePath}{file}`. In your case, it would use `\import{./}{Chapitre 1.tex}` and `\import{./}{Chapitre 2.tex}`.

Comment: Also, there is now a `Managing a large project` documentation in Overleaf. [Management in a large project](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project)